# Deserializing json as List<Object>

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have json:

```
"taxLevels": [{
        "code": "VAT",
        "percentage": 19.0
    }
]
```

This is truly `List<TTaxLevel>`

I have **Model.class**:

```
public class Model{

    private final List<TTaxLevel> taxLevels;
}
```

And **TTaxLevel.class**:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TTaxLevel {

    private String code;
    private Double percentage;
}
```

But I receive error here:

> [Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
> java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> out of
> START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of
> java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> out of
> START_ARRAY token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 36, column:
> 19] (through reference chain: ...Model["taxLevels"])]]

Can I force somehow `jackson` to expect type here `ArrayList` instead of `Map`? This is an issue.

This is deserialization code:

```
 Model model =  new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, Model .class);
```

Comment: You haven't shown your deserialisation code.

Comment: @tgdavies I added

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You need to enclose current content into `{  }`

Answer (score 0):

Please add getter/setter methods to you classes and provide no-arg constructor.
Also you json is not completely valid, it should be:

```json
{
  "taxLevels": [
    {
      "code": "VAT",
      "percentage": 19.0
    }
  ]
}
```

I trided putting it inside resource folder, fetch and then response to a sample request. Here is the sample code:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class Model {
    private List<TTaxLevel> taxLevels;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class TTaxLevel {
    private String code;
    private Double percentage;
}

@RequestMapping("tax-level")
@RestController
class SampleRequestBody {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    SampleRequestBody(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Map<String, Model> taxLevel(@RequestBody Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final Map<String, Model> response = new HashMap<>(1);
        response.put("data",  model);
        return response;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Model getTaxLevel() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("tax-level.json").getInputStream();
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Model.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues:

1. You need to provide getters and setters for your classes since the fields are all private;
2. You need to change the Json to include "{" at the beginning and "}" at the end.

```
    {
        "taxLevels": [{
                "code": "VAT",
                "percentage": 19.0
            }
        ]
    }
```